# interp2 with for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, interpolation

> %I_Phase [0 51.1111 102.2222 153.3333 204.4444 255.5556 306.6667 357.7778 408.8889 460]
>
> %Theta [-45    -30 -15 0   15  30  45  60  75  90]
>
> %Torque_Matrix [0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> 28.6989 35.9452 41.1581 43.8173 43.5092 40.0174 33.4011 24.0388 12.6221 0.0940
> 52.6956 67.7241 79.8022 87.4465 89.2066 84.0131 71.5044 52.2439 27.7582 0.3762
> 71.9900 95.3367 115.9323    130.8876    137.0923    131.9869    114.3100    84.6153 45.4083 0.8464
> 86.5822 118.7830    149.5483    174.1406    187.1661    183.9389    161.8178    121.1530    65.5724 1.5047
> 96.4722 138.0630    180.6504    217.2055    239.4282    239.8691    214.0278    161.8569    88.2505 2.3511
> 101.6600    153.1768    209.2385    260.0824    293.8785    299.7776    270.9400    206.7272    113.4425    3.3856
> 102.1456    164.1242    235.3126    302.7711    350.5170    363.6642    332.5544    255.7637    141.1486    4.6082
> 97.9289 170.9054    258.8727    345.2718    409.3438    431.5290    398.8711    308.9666    171.3687    6.0188
> 89.0100 173.5203    279.9188    387.5844    470.3588    503.3720    469.8900    366.3357    204.1028    7.6176]

I have two vectors `(I_Phase1, Theta1)` and one matrix `(Torque_Matrix)`, I need to do a interpolation with `interp2`, but my fuction and loop when running interp2, Theta_Int and I_Phase_Int values ​​are only 90 and 460 respectively, so I only have a value for Torque_Value and I need values ​​at -45: 90 and 0: 460, I need to create a new array with Torque_Values ​​values. I need help, please.

```
surf(Theta1,I_Phase1,Torque_Matrix);
hold on
Matrix_int = zeros(100);
index_Theta = 0;
index_I = 0;

for Theta_Int = -45:90;  

for I_Phase_Int = 0:460;  
   
Torque_Value = interp2(Theta1,I_Phase1,Torque_Matrix,Theta_Int,I_Phase_Int);
   
 end        
end
 
surf(Theta_Int,I_Phase_Int,Torque_Value,'.r');
```

Comment: why is it not working?

Comment: You don't need any `for` loops at all, removing them and using the documented capabilities of `interp2` is likely to solve your problem

Comment: "It's not working" is not useful. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work

Comment: Ander Biguri not working because in time wheels the interp2, the values of Theta_Int and I_Phase_Int are 90 and 460 respectively, so have just one value for Torque_Value and I need values in -45:90 and 0:460, I need create a new matrix with Torque_Values values

Comment: Because you are not storing the value, every time interp2 is called, you delete the previous value. Consider taking a programmin/MATLAB tutorial

Comment: If you set up `Theta_Int` and `I_Phase_Int` as 1 row and 1 column vector, you can put them directly into interp2 without any for loops, and Torque_Value will be a matrix, as described in the [documetation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html)

Comment: I dont have experience in Matlab, sorry

Comment: @etmuse like I doing `Theta_Int` and `I_Phase_Int` as row and column?

Comment: @PedroFranco yes, make one of them a row vector, the other one a column vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the interp2 function with vectors, but if it helps for a beginner as yourself to see what is going on in each step, for loops will still work.  You just need to create vectors for Theta_Int and I_Phase_Int.  Then when you call interp2, you index Theta_Int(j) and I_Phase_Int(k), as well as store the values in Torque_Value(k,j).  I swapped the for loops around so when you do the surf it will plot along the same axis as above.

```
Theta_Int = -45:90;
I_Phase_Int = 0:460;
for k = 1:length(I_Phase_Int)  
    for j = 1:length(Theta_Int)
        Torque_Value(k, j) = interp2(Theta,I_Phase,Torque_Matrix,Theta_Int(j),I_Phase_Int(k));
    end
end

figure();
surf(Theta_Int, I_Phase_Int, Torque_Value);
```

Also created a new figure so both of your plots will be shown.  So just replace your for loop down with this code and it should work.

Comment: thank you for your help! Now, for me use the interp2 function with vectors, what function need I using?

Comment: To do it with vectors, just get rid of the for loops and indexing on variables.  Also you need to transpose I_Phase_Int so that the dimensions look correct to matlab.  `Torque_Value = interp2(Theta, I_Phase, Torque_Matrix, Theta_Int, I_Phase_Int');`  The apostrophe on I_Phase_Int means to transpose the vector.